# Cardslib how can i make an transparent card

Tags: java, android, cardslib

I want to make something like this http://mobilesyrup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/playnewsstandmaterialdesign.png, where i uses cardslib, but can i make a "fake" card that is transparent? I want it to work so you can swipe down to show the background picture, and swipe up to show the cards.

-Mariogrip

Comment: I have tried this            parent.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().
                    getColor(android.R.color.transparent)); it just shows white

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make card transparent - use [`View#setAlpha(float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) to control transparency of your card.
Example:

```
cardView.setAlpha(.5f); //make it 50% transparent
```

Comment: Tried, it still white, is this working with cardslib? https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/